# Rename files in subfolders with parent folder names

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, nautilus, scripts

I have a main directory that has four folders `f1, f2, f3 and f4` each of these folders has 10 folders, and each of these 10 folders `ff1...ff10` has some `.jpeg` images with some names lets say `image1`.... and so on. What I want to know is how to rename these .jpeg images in each of these folders of the 10 folders in each of `f1, f2, f3 and f4`, so that I will concatenate the parent folders in the beginning of its name, for example of `image1.jpeg` is located in `f3/ff1` then its name will be `f3_ff1_image1.jpeg`, same with all the other images in the other 10 folders in each of the four main folders. If anyone can please advise how this can be done in a `.sh` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple file `changeName.sh` as follow:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    fileName=$(basename $1)
    filepath=$(dirname $1)
    secondDir=$(basename $filepath)
    firstDir=$(basename $(dirname $filepath))
    parentDir=$(basename $(dirname $(dirname $filepath)))
    mv $1 $filepath/${parentDir}_${firstDir}_${secondDir}_$fileName
```

save it, for example in `/home/yourUser/bin`.

Change permission to `changeName.sh`:

```
chmod +x /home/yourUser/bin/changeName.sh
```

Open you `/home/yourUser/.bashrc` file and add at the end this line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/yourUser/bin
```

save it and reload it:

```
source .bashrc
```

Now you have a new utility that can change name to file using folder as part of name.

Try this:

```
find mainDirectory -name "*.jpeg" -exec changeName.sh {} \;
```

`mainDirectory` can be absolute or relative.

Tested on lubuntu 12.04

---

[**dirname**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dirname.1.html) strip last component from file name while [**basename**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/basename.1.html) strip directory and suffix from filenames.

So to get third level of directory:

```
   parentDir=$(basename $(dirname $(dirname $filepath)))
```

Comment: could you tell me, what if I want to rename using one higher level? so that I will include the parent folder of `f1`,`f2`,`f3` or `f4`, so that the name will include one more higher folder level name?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: and where I'm going to put this in `changeName.sh`? , sorry for asking but I'm a beginner.

Comment: Sorry, I updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

With a loop and some bash string manipulations

```
while read -rd $'\0' f; do 
  d="${f%/*}"; p="${d/\//_}";
  echo mv -- "$f" "${d}/${p}_${f##*/}"
done < <(find -type f -name '*.jpeg' -printf '%P\0')
```

(remove the `echo` once you've confirmed it matches the files correctly)

With the perl-based `rename` command and bash `globstar`

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -nv -- 's|(f\d+)/(ff\d+)/(image\d+)|$1/$2/$1_$2_$3|' **/*.jpeg
```

(remove the `-nv` once you've confirmed it matches the files correctly)